# Changing Magento File Paths

Tags: magento, filepath

I was passed down a modded Magento application to do some modifications on and this is my first time using this kind of application. After rolling in pain for a day or two I finally managed to migrate the database. When I was trying to modify some CSS file I was stupefied to see it has no effect, then after an element inspection this came on

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://kicartonne.fr/js/mage/translate.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://kicartonne.fr/js/mage/cookies.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kicartonne.fr/skin/frontend/default/ki_cartonn/css/reset.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kicartonne.fr/skin/frontend/default/ki_cartonn/css/boxes.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kicartonne.fr/skin/frontend/default/ki_cartonn/css/menu.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kicartonne.fr/skin/frontend/default/default/css/clears.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kicartonne.fr/skin/frontend/default/default/css/print.css" media="print" />
```

All file paths come off as absolute! How can I fix this? I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under System->Configuration->Web(pretty sure) change the base url to the site you're wanting. If you're inspecting element on it, of course it's going to be absolute, that's how HTML works. The content is being generated dynamically at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, I figured some of this stuff out.